# Возможно ли, "Отменить ClearInterval"?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Есть функция которая cрабатывает каждые несколько секунд. При определенном действии пользователя, допустим скролл, срабатывает ClearInterval.

```
const timerId = setInterval(() => someFunc(), 1900);

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
 clearInterval(timerId);

});
```

Есть ли способ вернуть тот же самый интервал, если пользователь больше не скроллит?

Comment: Можно, например, запускать `clearInterval`, обернув его в `setTimeout` и при надобности тот `setTimeout` прибить. Т.о. `clearInterval` не наступит. А можно просто еще раз запускать `clearInterval` с нужной функцией. Т.е. выбор тут есть. ;)